# Remove all the callbacks from an HTML element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `select` menu that, on change through AJAX, generates another `select` menu, which in turn on change generates yet another `select` menu with yet another callback on change (lets say `alert(chosenValue)`). By working my way through these `select` menus the first time, I generate correctly the content for the second and third `select`, and the alert is printed correctly.

From the second time onward, when I generate new content for the third `select`, when choosing an option, multiple alerts are fired with the elements that were at that position in the `select`. I am guessing that these callbacks where generated and stayed there, because I generated them with `$("select#dropdownMenu3").change(function() {...});`.

Is there a way to remove such generated callbacks and have a "virgin" `select#dropdownMenu3` again? I'm using jQuery, so big pluses if the solution includes it! Thanks!

EDIT: code becasue - reEDIT: I'm starting to thing that the problem is far more serious. Here is the *whole* thing

```
/*All the variables that you see used are defined somewhere up here*/
$("select#dropdownMenu1").change(function(){
          $('select#dropdownMenu3').unbind('change');
          var typeChosen = $(this).children(":selected").html();
          if(!searchSuggestions){
          $.get( "/searchdata", function( data ) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            searchSuggestions = data;
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
              if(data[i].type == typeChosen){
                $("#dropdownMenu2").empty();
                $("#dropdownMenu2").append("<option disabled>Choose a Predicate</option>");
                for(var j = 0; j < data[i].predicates.length; j++){
                    $("#dropdownMenu2").append("<option value='" + j + "'>" + data[i].predicates[j].predicate + "</option>");
                }
              }
            }
            $("#dropdownMenu2").select2();
            $("select#dropdownMenu2").change(function(){
              predicateChosenIndex = parseInt($(this).children(":selected").val());
              $("#tdDropdownMenu3").html("");
              $('#tdDropdownMenu3').append("<select class=\"js-example-basic-multiple\" id=\"dropdownMenu3\"><option disabled>Choose an Object</option></select>");
              for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                if(data[i].type == typeChosen){
                  for(var k = 0; k < data[i].predicates[predicateChosenIndex].values.length; k++){
                    $("#dropdownMenu3").append("<option value='" + k + "'>" + data[i].predicates[predicateChosenIndex].values[k].value + "</option>");
                  }
                }
              }
              $("#dropdownMenu3").select2();
              $("select#dropdownMenu3").change(function(){
                objectChosenIndex = parseInt($(this).children(":selected").val());
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                  if(data[i].type == typeChosen){
                    alert(data[i].predicates[predicateChosenIndex].values[objectChosenIndex].value + " chosen");
                  }
                }
              });
            });
          });
        }
```

Comment: It's hardly to say with this shared information.

Comment: I thought it was a simple jQuery function call. Here you have the code.

Comment: Please provide all necessary code, that includes your html (generation)... Now it's like you are going to a mechanic and telling him your car doesn't work and saying to him "Here are the two front tires, where is the problem?"

Comment: Have you tried `unbind` or `off` jQuery options?

Comment: tried `off`, didn't work!

Comment: Sorry for double reply - added the whole HTML generation code because I'm starting to think the problem is not just an unbind issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('select#dropdownMenu3').unbind('change');
```

But as long as we don't see how you generate your html, this might not be the best solution.

Comment: I added the HTML generation code. I'm starting to think that the problem I have is far more than just unbinding a callback, which unfortunately did not work. As you can see I also tried to remove the entire element and recreate it, without success. The callbacks still tend to accumulate on the last `select` menu.